# Slowing process down by clicking multiple times in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, click

I'm working on my own CMS system. It works partly in Ajax and jQuery, but the problem is that I'm using a lot of click events. So, when I keep clicking on different items in my website, it slows the system down. Eventually it doesn't do anything anymore. Am I right about the click event and how do I need to use it in the good way? I used the .bind and .on event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//Standards
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('#wrapper').css('width',windowWidth);
$('#content').css('height',windowHeight);


//Click related items
$('.listItem').bind('click',function() {
    var itemID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#content').load('showitems.php',{newID:itemID});
});


//Click on tab
$('.liBase a').on('click', function() {
    $('.liBase a').parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().addClass('activeList');
});


//Click pages

$('.page').on('click', function() {
    var pageID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('showpages.php',{newID:pageID});
});

$('.item').on('click', function() {
    var pageID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('showitems.php',{newID:pageID});
});

$('.editItem').on('click', function() {
    var newID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.editPage').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('edititem.php',{itemID:newID});
});

$('.editPage').on('click',function() {
    var newID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('editpage.php',{pageID:newID});
});

$('.deleteItem').on('click', function() {
    var newID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('../control/deleteRecords.php',{postID:newID,tblName:'items',tblID:'itemID'});
});

$('.deletePage').on('click',function() {

    var newID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('../control/deleteRecords.php',{postID:newID,tblName:'pages',tblID:'pageID'});
});

$('#addPage').on('click', function() {
    $('#content').load('addpage.php');
});

$('#addItem').on('click', function() {
    $('#content').load('additem.php');
});


$('#imageShow a').on('click', function() {
    var pageID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).parent().addClass('activeList');
    $('#content').load('showimages.php');

});

$('#imageAdd').on('click', function() {
    $('#content').load('addimage.php');
});



});
```

Comment: Get chrome, hit f12 and click the network tab and see if any of the ajax requests are taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the following (easy ones first;D)

1) cache jQuery Object you often use.

```
 $item = $('.item');
```

2) refactor your code to remove redundancies

```
$('.editPage').on('click',function() {
    doStuff(this);
    $('#content').load('editpage.php',{pageID:newID});
});

function doStuff(that){
    var newID = $(that).attr('rel');
    $('.liBase').parent().parent().removeClass('activeList');
    $('#imageShow').removeClass('activeList');
    $(that).parent().parent().addClass('activeList');
}
```

3) see if you can limit the number of click-events bound (are there elements which have needlessly bound several click-events?)

4) Do profiling (Chrome devtools is a good choice for that)

- is it the Network - limit the frequency of Request by discarding old ones or queuing them
- profile you memory-consumption - do you parts in your code consuming a lot of memory